# task-relation graph based on JIRA

Tags: jira, issue-tracking

I am wondering is there any tool which can help visualize relations between tasks/bugs, I mean dependencies like related to/blocks/clone/etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is the Links Hierarchy plugin, though I'm not sure if that supports JIRA 4.4. 
There is also the REST example at https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Version+2+Tutorial#JIRARESTAPIVersion2Tutorial-Example%231%3AGraphingImageLinks

Comment: the linking to the draw-chart.py on that page is broken. Here is the source code: https://developer.atlassian.com/download/attachments/4227078/draw-chart.py?version=2&modificationDate=1285030688582

Answer (score 2):

[Vivid Trace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/vivid.trace) visualizes relations between tasks/bugs for any/all of the issue link types you mention, and it can graph a given issue, component, version, or even a whole project.
https://vivid-inc.net/

*(Disclaimer: We make it.)*

Comment: Any plans on supporting JIRA cloud?

Comment: @JohnHunt Nothing to announce at this time, but I'd be happy to keep you informed!